# Сamunda replace behaviour for external tasks in tests

Tags: spring, spring-test, bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

I created simple Camunda spring boot project and also created [simple BPMN process](https://github.com/Kejam/camunda-test/blob/master/src/main/resources/process.bpmn) with switcher.  (5.5 KB)

I used service task with external implementation as a spring beans. I want to write tests for process but I don't want to test how beans works. Because in general I use external implementation for connection to DB and save parameter to context or REST call to internal apps. For example I want skip execute service task(one) and instead set variables for switcher. I tried to use camunda-bpm-assert-scenario for test process and wrote simple test WorkflowTest.

I noticed if I use @MockBean for One.class then Camunda skip delegate execution. If use @Mock then Camunda execute delegate execution.

PS Sorry for bad english

One

> @Service
> public class One implements JavaDelegate {
> private final Random random = new Random();
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
>     System.out.println("Hello, One!");
>     execution.setVariable("check", isValue());
> }
>
> public boolean isValue() {
>     return random.nextBoolean();
> }
> ```
>
> }

WorkflowTest

> @SpringBootTest
> @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
> @Deployment(resources = "process.bpmn")
> public class WorkflowTest extends AbstractProcessEngineRuleTest {
>
> ```
> @Mock
> private ProcessScenario insuranceApplication;
>
> @MockBean
> private One one;
>
> @Before
> public void init() {
>     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
>     Mocks.register("one", one);
> }
>
> @Test
> public void shouldExecuteHappyPath() throws Exception {
>     // given
>     when(insuranceApplication.waitsAtServiceTask("Task_generator")).thenReturn(externalTaskDelegate -> {
>                 externalTaskDelegate.complete(withVariables("check", true));
>             }
>     );
>
>     String processDefinitionKey = "camunda-test-process";
>     Scenario scenario = Scenario.run(insuranceApplication)
>             .startByKey(processDefinitionKey) // either just start process by key ...
>             .execute();
>
>     verify(insuranceApplication).hasFinished("end_true");
>     verify(insuranceApplication, never()).hasStarted("three");
>     verify(insuranceApplication, atLeastOnce()).hasStarted("two");
>
>     assertThat(scenario.instance(insuranceApplication)).variables().containsEntry("check", true);
> }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

I found two solutions:

1. It's a little hack. If user @MockBean for delegate in a test. The delegate will be skipped but you have trouble with process engine variables.
2. Create two beans with one qualifier and use profiles for testing and production. I used to default profile for local start and test profile for testing.